# If I use paintComponent, how do I show a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, paintcomponent

I'm relatively new to Java, and I was making a game where you dash up and down to avoid obstacles. I was almost done with all the main features, and had to do the score system and the background. Thinking the score would be easier, I wrote out a JLabel and added it to my JFrame. It flashed and disappeared. I'm fairly certain this is because I add the whole graphics method directly after, or something like that. But, if I add the JLabel after, that's all that gets added, and it takes up the whole screen.

```
package dash;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener {//ignore yellow line
//setting up class
    Variables var = new Variables();
    Timer timer = new Timer(5,this);
    boolean spacePressed;
    boolean gameActive = false;
    boolean creatingObstacles = true;
    int arrayLength;
    int creationStep = 50;
    int backgroundx;
    int speed = 30;
    int x;
    int y;
    int playery = 700;
    int highscore;
    int score = 1;
    static int[] obstacles = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
//making label
    JLabel label = new JLabel("score: " + score);
//setting up graphics method
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
//player
        ImageIcon player = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\myname\\Documents\\Eclipse Projects\\dash\\player.png");
        player.paintIcon(this,g,300,playery);
//label properties
        label.setBounds(300,900,100,100);
//Some really cool code that took a while to write, this is going to generate random obstacles so I don't
//have to make all the levels since I'm lazy. This also makes graphics easier, since now I don't have
//to draw out the map taking up a lot of memory, at least several gigs probably more, for small levels. 
        int min = 500;
        int max = 1500;
        arrayLength = obstacles.length - 1;
//creating random array, im really proud of this
//code. it took me hours to write and looks badass
//except i have no clue how to label anything now T-T
        while (creationStep > 0) {
            if (creatingObstacles == true) {
                obstacles[arrayLength] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min) + var.previousNumber;
                var.previousNumber = obstacles[arrayLength];
                arrayLength--;
                creationStep--;
                if (arrayLength == -1) {
                    creatingObstacles = false;
                    arrayLength = obstacles.length - 1;
                }}}
//drawing with the array
//ps i have no clue why this works, but it does
        boolean onTop = true;
        
        while (arrayLength >= 0) {
//drawing obstacles
            ImageIcon obstacle = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\myname\\Documents\\Eclipse Projects\\dash\\obstacle.png");
            obstacle.paintIcon(this,g,obstacles[arrayLength] + backgroundx,y);
//checking collision
            if (obstacles[arrayLength] + backgroundx >= 300 && obstacles[arrayLength] + backgroundx <= 400 && y == playery) {
                spacePressed = false;
                gameActive = false;
                backgroundx = 0;
            }
//finishing loop
            arrayLength--;
//deciding if it puts the obstacle on top or bottom
            if (onTop) {
                y = 200;
            } else {
                y = 700;
            }
//toggling onTop boolean
            onTop = !onTop;
        }
//when to make a new array
        if (obstacles[0] <= -backgroundx) {
            var.previousNumber = -backgroundx + 2000;
            creationStep = 50;
            creatingObstacles = true;
            speed = speed + 5;
        }
//pause
        if (gameActive == false) {
            ImageIcon pauseScreen = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\myname\\Documents\\Eclipse Projects\\dash\\pausescreen.png");
            pauseScreen.paintIcon(this,g,0,0);
        }
//timer, this starts physics
        timer.start();
    }
//setting up keys
    KeyListener key = new KeyListener() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
                gameActive = !gameActive;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if(e.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE && gameActive == true) {
                spacePressed = !spacePressed;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }
    };
//physics go here
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (spacePressed == true) {
            playery = 200;
        } else {
            playery = 700;
        }
//movement
        if (gameActive == true) {
            backgroundx = backgroundx - speed;
        }
        repaint();
        }   
//main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//implementing method
        Main main = new Main();
//creating frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.setSize(1920,1080);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addKeyListener(main.key);
        frame.add(main.label);
        frame.add(main);
    }
}
class Variables{
    int previousNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    frame.add(main.label);
    frame.add(main);
```

The default layout manager for the frame is the BorderLayout.

You can't add two components to the "CENTER" of the BorderLayout, which is the default if you don't specify a constraint.

Try the following to see the difference:

```
    frame.add(main.label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    frame.add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information on how the BorderLayout and other layout managers work.

Comment: Still not displaying anything, I even tried moving the JLabel into the main method and then the graphics didn’t show up, just the label. I changed it to what you wrote, nothing else was added.

Comment: Did you read the tutorial? Start with the working demo in the tutorial. It will show you how to better structure your code. So first just attempt to display the label and your panel that just paints a rectangle. The label should NOT be modified in the paintComponent method. Then, once that works, you add in the game logic. You should NOT be writing the entire application before you start testing. The tutorial also has a section on "Custom Painting". Start with the basics.

Comment: yup, i got it to work. had to flip the order that i add the 2 things, and i moved the label out of the paintcomponent method as you suggested.